# Update EntityKey Reference in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, workflow-foundation, entity-relationship

I created an application that uses Asp.net, Entity Framework and Windows Workflow Foundation and everything works as expected.

My asp.net page should start a Workflow that executes and update an entity passed to the workflow from the page. Everything works ok: i used Unit Of Work pattern to share the context between asp.net and WWF and my entity is successfully updated during the workflow... except a field that is modelled in my entity as a reference to another entity.

Suppose this case. The main entity is called Item that has a property called Status that is a foreign key to another entity called Status. When i create an Item, i just create it with the common syntax like

```
Item i = new Item();
```

I then create the reference to Status entity like this:

```
i.StatusReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("myEntities.StatusSet", "idStatus", State);
```

where State is an integer value hardcoded in the Workflow step.

Whenever I try to update this Entity (the Item one) i follow these steps:
a) I retrieve the Entity from the context (a new one, built as Unit Of Work for the following transaction) using:

```
Item i = (from item in ctx.ItemsSet where item.idItem == itemID select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Entity is then attached to my context. EntityState is in UNCHANGED

b) I update the Status reference like before:

```
i.StatusReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("myEntities.StatusSet", "idStatus", State);
```

c) I save changes on the context like:
ctx.SaveChanges();

Using vs2008 debugger i can see the updated entity and when changes are saved... i see all properties changed (modifiedDate, itemName and other props) but entity reference still points at the original one.

Can anyone give me some help?!

Comment: You mention that the other properties are changed - are you doing that in code that you're omitting, or are you using a binder?

Comment: Why do you use i.StatusReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey(...) and not simply i.Status = myState? (with both i and myState in the same context).