# Entity Framework, changing EntityKey leaves Entity as "UnChanged"

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity with a status property that I would like to update.

I would like to do the following:

```
const int NEW_STATUS = 2;
myEntity.StatusReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("SetName", "KeyName", NEW_STATUS);
```

When this is passed to the context, its state is "UnChanged", despite me changing the relationship!  This means the save will not be persisted.

The entity comming in is from a different context to the one that its being attached to and saved.

Anyone know how I can update just the entitykey and persist it!?

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can't. EntityKeys are designed to be mapped to primary keys, which, in any good DB design, will never change. If you've mapped your EntityKey to something which is not a PK, change it to the PK. If your DB design calls for PKs to change, please reconsider that design.</s> (Removed after you changed the question.)

Added, upon re-reading the question: Are you actually wanting to update *the EntityKey of the entity*, or do you just want to change the status property? If the latter, try one of the following:

```
entity.Status = someStatusInstance;
```

...or...

```
entity.StatusReference.EntityKey = myEntity.EntityKey = new EntityKey("SetName", "KeyName", NEW_STATUS);
```

If your entity state isn't modified, you probably have the order of operations wrong when adding to/saving the context. You would need to show that when asking for help on it.

Comment: The latter, I tried "entity.Status = someStatusInstance", however that doesnt work due to the entity being in a different context from the one where I retrived the status from!  I know the value for the FK I want to update, so dont need the round trip either :)

Comment: Not sure the ordering is wrong.. seems like a common problem, however I cant seem to find a suitable solution!  This guy has a simular problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178885/update-entitykey-reference-in-entity-framework

Comment: Believe me, it's wrong. We do this *all the time* and I can guarantee you it works. I will add that using multiple contexts concurrently is going to confuse even EF experts. Avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Its passing the entities through layers, and I didnt want to use my context as a singleton!  I want something like "ApplyProperties" however it doesnt work on entityRelationships http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/87f63056-7309-41af-8be7-313c20594bde/

Comment: And there is not much to get wrong on the ordering... pull entity from the database, update just the entitykey for one of the FK's and call savechanges...

Comment: I'm not saying you *can'* use multiple contexts. It does work, but expect it to be more confusing than using just one. There is quite a bit you need to do in just the right order which you don't need to do with only one context.

Comment: Took your advice, and used a single context for that particular set of operations :) thanks..